Custom Authentication Power BI report server
form
Getting error
An error occurred while attempting to verify the user.
I am using custom form authentication to open the URL without username and password.
After applying the changes in configuration file getting this error.

An error occurred while attempting to verify the user. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

We did customer security ASP.NET developer create a form logon page by passing the authentication and also generate customer security .dll.
After this we had done changes in the configuration files we put the .dllfile in bin, portal after doing the changes in rsconfig and web config the server is start successfully but when I open the URL it will taking to the form page displaying username and password with two buttons register user and logon.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.
